# show total number of unread notification like Fb in react native

Tags: notifications

i want show to total number of unread notification in my react native app like it shows in facebook top navigation icon like[image] i am using raact native nodejs mongo db

Answer (score -1):

```
 try {

      const val = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('details'))
      const count = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Countn')
      console.log('this local count ', count)

      fetch(link + 'notification/getCustomerNotificationsCount?customerId=' + val.id)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(async (responseJson) => {
          console.log('Notification Count', responseJson);

          if (responseJson.result  >count) {
            console.log('this is if ', count);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('Countn', JSON.stringify(responseJson.result))
            this.setState({ Nflag: val-count, })

          }
          else {
            console.log('this.is else', responseJson, count,  this.state.Nflag);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('Countn',JSON.stringify(responseJson.result))
            
          }

        }).catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        })

    } catch (e) {

    }
```